# VBA help. Column A divide Column B and put answer in Column C for every row

Tags: vba, excel

In my worksheet (named "Sheet1") I have 388 rows of data. For each row, I want to be able to divide values in Column A by Values in Column B, and put this answer to column C. I would like to keep up this pattern going until the last column. So after the 1st round of calculation, it goes to column D, column D gets divided by column E, and values go into column F.

I want to be able to apply it to every row until the last row and every column until the last column.

I guess I need to use an offset? Any ideas/suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: So you want to perform this calculation for all 388 rows and then how many columns?  "till the last column" could mean a few different things.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for - couldn't that just be a simple formula, no VBA necessary? `=A1/B1` and then put that in C1.  Then copy and in F1, paste - formula will become `=D1/E1` ?

Comment: @user3578951 yes, it can be just a simple formula and apply it down but there are like 170 columns, and I wanted to be able to apply the same code to my other worksheets as well.

Comment: @TMH8885 the last column would be Column FO, so in FP there should be values that are FN/FO

Comment: I guess I should say apply the calculation till an entirely empty row and entirely empty column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this. Untested, but should provide a framework.

```
condition=True
xrowx=1
xcolx=3

Do While condition=True
    with Sheets("Sheet1")
        tempA=.Cells(xrowx,xcolx-2).Value
        tempB=.Cells(xrowx,xcolx-1).Value
        .Cells(xrowx,xcolx)=tempA/tempB

        xrowx=xrowx+1
        if xrowx>Worksheetfunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(1,xcolx-1),.Cells(xrowx,xcolx-1))) then
            xrowx=1
            xcolx=xcolx+3
            if .Cells(xrowx,xcolx-1)=0 then
                exit do
            End if
        End if
    end with
loop
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This does help me a lot to understand what to do, I focused too much on using an offset function but I guess your if statement would work too. One thing though, .Cells(xrowx,xcolx)=tempA/tempB  this part appears to have an error, "Type mismatch", how should I fix it?

Comment: @BessieLee It's possible that the information in one of the cells is not in a number format (interger, long or double). You may want to add `Cdbl()` around the `.Cells(xrowx,xcolx-2).Value` and `.Cells(xrowx,xcolx-1).Value` (this will convert the data into the Double format) and see if that helps it.

Comment: I did cdbl(.Cells(xrowx, xcolx - 2).Value) and cdbl(.Cells(xrowx, xcolx - 1).Value) but it now tells me that tempA = CDbl(.Cells(xrowx, xcolx - 2).Value) is type mismatch

Comment: @BessieLee what kind of values does column A have? For whatever reason, VBA is not able to convert that data into a number.

Comment: do I need to do dim xrows, xcols before the condition = True statement

Comment: my column A is sum of all 1s from a if statement . 1 is the value when my if condition is true.

Comment: @BessieLee No, you shouldn't have to `Dim` those variables. Perhaps try to remove the `With` statement ans specify the sheet before each `.Cells()` piece. Also, if A contains a formula (sounds like it might), there is a possibility that VBA is trying to pull the entire formula in and us that as the cell value. There is a way around that, so that you can get the value that is displayed in the cell, but unfortunately I do no know it off the top of my head :\

Comment: weird, it worked somehow, I guess im having another issue now. some of my cells are empty, but I don't want the calculation to stop right there whenever the first empty cell appears. I wanna it to carry on till row 389 and column 172. is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @BessieLee Sure, change the second `if` condition to `if xrowx>=389 and xcolx>=172 then`

Comment: now it says Overflow on  .Cells(xrowx, xcolx) = tempA / tempB

Comment: @BessieLee You're working with some big numbers I would assume? You'd only get an overflow error if the numbers are too large for the program to handle.

Comment: I think its because I substituted all empty cells with 0, so when I do 0/Column B, overflow occurs. so to fix this, I added the following between tempB and Xrow=xrows+1 statement:                                         If tempA = 0 Then
           .Cells(xrowx, xcolx) = "NA"
        Else
           .Cells(xrowx, xcolx) = tempA / tempB
        End If

Comment: @BessieLee And that fixed your issue?

Comment: 'not sure what is the problem now, but it still doesn't work. and says application defined error

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution only for **C1** thru **C388**.  This macro will place formulas in the appropriate cells:

```
Sub Bessie()
   Range("C1:C388").Formula = "=A1/B1"
End Sub
```

each formula will be adjusted to match the row.

Update the macro for any other columns you wish to fill.